# Increasing the value of other meta sites

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

Bear with me on this one...

I have spent some time on several of the other SE sites, especially those currently in Beta.

I realise, after having spent many of the best days of my life (waffling) on this site, the importance of the meta site to the entire functioning of the main site. This is where the community tests their ideas and rallies their troops; including unfair or unacceptable behaviour.

The meta communities on other sites just don't seem to have the same weight, community, love as the meta.stackoverflow site.

What are your suggestions for increasing this engagement on other sites? Should moderators from other sites be trained/instructed/prodded on the importance of building up their meta site?

Do moderators from other sites have enough training to do tasks like moving questions from main site to meta, merging tags and building a FAQ or any other high level task?

Or is this something that will/should happen over time as the community grows the need and importance of the moderation will grow?

I see on my current site of choice there are many admin tasks and discussions that should be happening, but aren't. Should I be encouraging that site to be more like MSO or just relax and see how things go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have admin tasks and discussions that are not happening, why aren't you posting them? That's what meta is for. Meta isn't the responsibility of the Moderators. Meta is as much for the Community to ask questions and [form their self-governance](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

There's only so much pushing you can do to increase engagement where users don't feel a need. If there is a need and you're not using the meta site, well... nothing is going to happen by itself. The Moderators create system message about important events and tag meta questions as `featured` which pushes them to the main site. They know how to use the tools but their responsibility and effectiveness can only push the process so far. The site is *ultimately* the responsibility of the community that uses it.

The per-site meta communities are proportionally smaller because the sites are smaller and the network-wide issues are handled here. But the meta site is there if you need it.